# Active directory with external DNS

Tags: dns, active-directory, windows-server-2016

As a training purpose for school I would like to install an Active Directory with an external DNS.

Serveur A : WS2k16 - Role: DNS
Serveur B : WS2k16 - Role: ADS

Is it possible to do it this way?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You might get better help over at [sf] with this.

Answer (score 2):

Hosting DNS somewhere other than a domain controller (DC) is a valid configuration - one that is not uncommon in large enterprise environments. I often use ISC BIND to provide DNS for our Active Directory environment, and I've occasionally used stand-alone Windows DNS servers to host the DNS service. You lose some of the "magic" that Microsoft has added to their AD/DNS integration (e.g. AD-integrated DNS has hostnames replicated to all domain controllers for redundancy), but both DNS and AD function properly.

Provided the DC can made dynamic updates in the appropriate zones (e.g. _msdcs.domain.ccTLD), all of the host records AD needs get set up for you when you're using an external DNS server.

Even if the zones are *not* set up to allow the DC to make dynamic updates, the DC has a file in  %systemroot%\system32\config\netlogon.dns which contains the records that need to be manually created. Clients won't be able to *use* the domain until the DNS records are manually created, you've got the potential for something to change on the DC and require a manual update, and IIRC there are event log entries on the DC every reboot complaining about the failure to auto-register records. The configuration is not ideal, but it *does* work.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I tried for hours already without knowing what was wrong. 

Answer (score 0):

Using netlogon file solved the problem, many thanks.

I can now register new computers on the ADS.
Anyway the ne computer are not inserted in the DNS entries, any clue how to solve it?